# How to draw line by passing two points using JS

Tags: javascript, html, openseadragon

I was able to show floorplan(image) in my web-page with zoom-in and zoom-out features using Openseadragon JS, and user can drop points over the image using addOverlay method from Openseadragon.Now i wanted to draw line between these points as the user add new points.any help
Below is a sample function i tried 
 `

```
function drawLine(webPoint) {
    var points = document.getElementsByClassName("pointer");
    counter = points.length
    console.log(counter);

    if (points.length == 1) {
        console.log("inside if");
        //start and end points are same
        var startPoint=[webPoint['x'],webPoint['y']];
        var endPoint=[webPoint['x'],webPoint['y']];
    } else {
        //start and end points are diff
        console.log("inside else");
        for(var i=0; i<=points.length; i++) {
            if (i == counter) {
               console.log("set endpoint");
               console.log(i);
               var endPoint=[webPoint['x'],webPoint['y']];
            }
            if (i == (counter-1)) {
                console.log("set startpoint");
                console.log(i);
                var startPoint=[webPoint['x'],webPoint['y']];
//                var rect = points[i].getBoundingClientRect();
//                var startPoint=[rect.top, rect.left];
            }
        }
    }

    // Paperscript
    var canvas = document.getElementById('osd-overlaycanvas');
    paper.setup(canvas);
    var path = new paper.Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    var pointOne     = new paper.Point(100, 20);
    var pointTwo     = new paper.Point(150, 100);
    path.moveTo(pointOne);
    path.lineTo(pointOne.add(pointTwo));
    path.closed = true;
    paper.view.draw();


}`
```

Adding the code with the use of [OpenSeadragonFabricjsOverlay](https://github.com/altert/OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay)

```
var point = new OpenSeadragon.Point(x, y);
var viewpoint = viewer.viewport.deltaPointsFromPixelsNoRotate(point);
var options = {
                   scale: 1000
                   }
var overlay = this.viewer.fabricjsOverlay(options);
var line = new fabric.Line([ 'x1', 'y1', 'x2','y2 ], {
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 5,
            selectable: false
          });
overlay.fabricCanvas().add(line);
```

viewer initialization is as follows

```
viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "id_name",
        showNavigationControl: false,
        tileSources: tileSource.get(floorId),
        width:10
    });
```

Comment: Are you using the Paper plugin for OSD? There are a number of plugins you can use: http://openseadragon.github.io/#plugins ...that's a lot easier than trying to do it with plain OSD.

Comment: I tried Paper and Fabric plugins for OSD, and was  able to draw lines in the viewer but the lines are misplaced from the points,tried passing the default window coordinates of point elements to all of the viewport convertion methods but the exact point coordinates related to the OSD viewer is not calculated   ```var point = new OpenSeadragon.Point(x, y);
        var viewpoint = viewerwer.viewport.deltaPointsFromPixelsNoRotate(point); ```

Comment: @iangilman edited

Comment: After going through your code eg here [Drawer](https://codepen.io/iangilman/pen/ZQNWbo?editors=1111) with the help of **update-viewport** method  and **ctx** i would be able to draw lines. if there is a **ctx.strokeLine()** method

Comment: Unfortunately I think while the Fabric overlay uses viewport coordinates, the Paper overlay uses image coordinates, as does the Canvas overlay. I've recommended everyone standardize on viewport coordinates. Anyway, glad to hear you've got something working. Canvas doesn't have a `strokeLine`... instead you have to do something like beginPath, moveTo, lineTo, and then stroke. The cheat sheet I use is https://simon.html5.org/dump/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html